# Second layer disappears after joining two layers

Tags: layers

FYI I am working with Version 2.7

I have two layers/planes (not sure what to call them... I'm new to this):

1. Pavement
2. Striping

Where *Pavement* is the outline/border of a parking lot - this has not been filled in yet,
and *Striping* is a separate layer of the individual parking spot stripes, like your classic white stripes (rectangular faces).

When I tab into Object mode, then select *Pavement* and then shift+click *Striping* and join them (ctrl+j), the *Striping* layer disappears in the viewport... in the layers pane, its not there (as it should if youre joining layers). This occurs in reverse, if I select *Striping* first, and *Pavement* second. I cannot seem to find an answer, and none of my labmates have been able to resolve this.

If you need context... I am wanting to join these so I can 'cut out' where the stripes are so the layers don't overlap faces but share edges.

ALSO: my knife tool is not working at all in this program, so this is why I am having to do this work around.

Comment: Could you please include an informative screen-grab? If your 'Layers' are objects, this is the expected behaviour. Maybe a picture can show us what you want to achieve.

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your post 
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and upload images that show your 
current setup and illustrate the problem.See [How to upload an image 
to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491)